# What is Admob In-app Purchase ? How to use it?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, admob, in-app-billing

Can anyone tell me what is admob in-app purchase and what is the difference between admob in-app purchase and Google play in app billing ? Are they different ?

because i want to use in-app purchase to sell some items on my apps games like extra coins or levels etc.

I can't make a google wallet merchant account from my country so here i want to use in app purchase to earn some good revenue but i didn't get any good tutorial regarding admob in-app purchase. i heard about google play in-app billing but it requires merchant account so i am interested to know can i use admob in-app purchase to sell some extra levels in my games but how can implement admob in-app purchase in my app.

i read a tutorial from google site but i didn't understand it. i'm interested to know is there any better tutorial available to learn admob in-app purchase and how to implement ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the AdMob In-app purchase house ads. It's a format of interstitial ads that you can use to promote your In-app item. I have create an App to showcase this format ( link to Google Play download page: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bindu.bpan.admobexample).

Anyway, it's just a ads type. You would still need to setup the in-app products in google play console. Therefore it requires you to have a google wallet merchant account.

Comment: GooglePlay seems to have butchered your app too! :P